# Show hidden HTML elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following in the `<body>` of my HTML

```
<div class="exact">
<div> <a id ="button_some_id" href="#"> Toggle Hidden </a></div>
<div id="item_some_id" hidden>This is hided</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#button_some_id").click(function() {$("#item_some_id").toggle();});
</script>
</div>
```

[Link to jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj8o8gwf/1/)

The idea here is I want someone to be able to click on the `Toggle Hidden` link and it will show some hidden content (and when it is clicked again, hide it).  However the javascript is not being triggered.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your code is fine, it simply isn't linking in the jQuery library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't inputted JQuery or JQuery UI into your JSFiddle's resources. Once putting them in, it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/tj8o8gwf/2/

```
$("#button_some_id").click(function() {$("#item_some_id").toggle();}); //works fine
```

Look at the **External Resources** section on the left hand side of the fiddle.

Comment: You don't need to use External Resources for jquery. Select it as a framework from the Javascript menu.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure the DOM is loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#button_some_id").click(function() {$("#item_some_id").toggle();});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that jQuery is inputted

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#button_some_id", function () {
        $("#item_some_id").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Unless the element is created dynamically, there's no reason to use delegation syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
//HTML
<div class="toBeHidden" hidden>This is hided</div>



//JS inside your click
if ($(".toBeHidden").is(":visible"))
{
    $(".toBeHidden").hide('slow');
}
else
{
    $(".toBeHidden").show('slow');
}
```

Comment: Isn't this what `.toggle()` does? Why write it out when there's a perfectly good function that does it.

Comment: And this won't work when there are multiple elements that match the class. It will toggle them all based on the first element's visibility.

Comment: Well, just to be sure that we are in the same page, I did not find any error in sedavidw code. The issue could be the version he was using (I don't know). I remember some time ago that toggle was about to be deprecated from jquery. I gave him another option.  " this won't work when there are multiple elements that match the class". That was not asked. There is only one (1) element in the page. If he had more, .each could be in hand !!!!

Comment: The error in the sedavidw code is that he didn't load jQuery into the fiddle. The only part of jQuery toggle that was deprecated and removed is the form that takes and event and two functions, and calls them alternately when the event occurs. The form that toggles visibility is not going away.

Comment: Why did you switch from an ID (like in the question) to a class if you didn't want your answer to generalize to multiple elements?